# Tests do not run in the specified order in JUnit5

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, kotlin, junit5

I am new to Kotlin, Java and IntelliJ and I have been pulling my hair since the past few hours and i need some help.

I need my tests to run in a specific order. I know that it is not recommended, but these are integration and workflow tests and not unit tests. For some reason, JUnit 5 totally ignored the test order in IntelliJ and runs the tests in a random order. I wrote a simple piece of code to check this and the behaviour is totally random.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder

@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation::class)
class OrderedTests
{

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    fun `A Test`()
    {
        println("First Test")
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    fun `A Second Test`()
    {
        println("Second Test")
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    fun `A FFFF Test`()
    {
        println("Third Test")
    }

    @Test
    @Order(4)
    fun `1 Test`()
    {
        println("Fourth Test")
    }

    @Test
    @Order(5)
    fun `AA Test`()
    {
        println("Fifth Test")
    }

    @Test
    @Order(6)
    fun `MM Test`()
    {
        println("Sixth Test")
    }
}
```

Here is how my pom.xml dependencies look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.arvatoinfoscore.lab.ad.wf</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummytest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <version.java>11.0.4</version.java>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit.jupiter.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.50</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using IntelliJ to run my tests and the run order is always the same: Fifth Test, Second Test, Third Test, Fourth Test, Sixth Test and First Test.

Any help to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `junit-jupiter-engine` as a dependency. Add this to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. i thought junit-jupiter-engine came bundled with IntelliJ. but this helped to fix the issue.

Comment: I've got that dependency 5.8.1 and does not do ordering, @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class) set

Answer (score 0):

As you said order should be irrelevant, take a look a this https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/48